# Hibernate Search/JPA - Can't create initial index; program hangs AFTER apparent index creation

Tags: hibernate, search, jpa, indexing, hibernate-search

I have been trying to use Hibernate Search with JPA for two days and I have everything compiling cleanly and
running without any obvious errors. However, when I try to create an initial index, the program runs and prints out each
object it is indexing (using manual indexing), then prints the "Indexing Completed" message. No no errors are thrown, 
but the main method never exits. I am running in Eclipse Kepler in a Maven project with jre1.7 so I can kill the processing by hitting the red stop button.
If I do that, then do a file search for index files, I don't find any. If I run my search program, I get
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: None of the specified entity types or any of their subclasses are indexed.

I would really appreaciate any suggestions on how to get this to work. I've tried going back to version 4.2
of hibernate search and I get the same thing.

The Domain class is a Car. Here is the Indexer output:

```
    Indexing: Make Infinity Model G35
    Indexing: Make Honda Model Civic
    Indexing: Make Audi Model A4
    Indexing: Make Toyota Model Carolla
    Indexing Completed
```

If run in the debugger the debug window shows the following active threads when the program should have exited:

```
com.xyzco.search.Indexer at localhost:52231 
    Daemon Thread [MySQL Statement Cancellation Timer] (Running)    
    Thread [Hibernate Search: Index updates queue processor for index com.xyzco.search.Car-1] (Running) 
    Thread [Hibernate Search: IndexWriter worker executor for com.xyzco.search.Car-1] (Running) 
    Thread [DestroyJavaVM] (Running)
```

Here is the Indexer code:

```
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;
import org.hibernate.search.jpa.FullTextEntityManager;

public class Indexer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = Persistence
                    .createEntityManagerFactory("dbschema");
            EntityManager em = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();

            FullTextEntityManager ftem = org.hibernate.search.jpa.Search
                    .getFullTextEntityManager(em);
            ftem.getTransaction().begin();

            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            List<Car> cars = em.createQuery(
                    "select c from Car c").getResultList();
            for (Car car : cars) {
                ftem.index(car); // manually index an item instance
                System.out.println("Indexing: Make " + car.getMake() + " Model " + car.getModel());
            }
            ftem.getTransaction().commit(); // index are written at commit time
            em.close();
            System.out.println("Indexing Completed");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the Car class code:

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;

import org.hibernate.search.annotations.Analyze;
import org.hibernate.search.annotations.DocumentId;
import org.hibernate.search.annotations.Field;
import org.hibernate.search.annotations.Index;
import org.hibernate.search.annotations.Indexed;
import org.hibernate.search.annotations.Store;

@Entity
@Indexed  //Mark for indexing
public class Car {

    @Id @GeneratedValue
    @DocumentId  //Mark id property shared by Core and Search
    private Integer id;

    @Field   //Mark for indexing using tokenization
    private String make;

    @Field  
    private String model;

    @Field(index=Index.YES, analyze=Analyze.NO, store=Store.NO)
    private String description;

    @Field(index=Index.YES, analyze=Analyze.NO, store=Store.NO)
    private String options;

    // getters and setters left out...

}
```

Here is persistence.xml

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd"
    version="1.0">
    <persistence-unit name="dbschema"> <!--  transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL"> -->
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <class>com.xyzco.search.Car</class> 
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>

            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/referencedata"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value=""/>

            <property name="hibernate.search.default.directory_provider"
                value="filesystem" />
            <property name="hibernate.search.default.indexBase" value="/usr/lucene/indexes" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Here is part of the POM (Uses profile suggested on Hibernate site)

```
...
<profile>
    <id>jboss-public-repository</id>
...         
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${sl4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.14</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- HIBERNATE SEARCH -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-search</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
        <artifactId>lucene-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: In the Indexer class, after closing the Entity Manager (em.close) you must close the Entity Manager Factory (entityManagerFactory.close();) or else the program will hang. This is explained in the FAQ list and is a common problem, but it is surprising how many examples only show fragments of code and don't include this line.

Answer (score 0):

In the Indexer class, after closing the Entity Manager (em.close) you must close the Entity Manager Factory (entityManagerFactory.close();) or else the program will hang. This is explained in the FAQ list and is a common problem, but it is surprising how many examples only show fragments of code and don't include this line.